# html5 cache manifest file that requires network - event to detect shortcut click?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, manifest

I have a html5 page with a manifest file that requires network:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
```

There is a Google Chrome shortcut from the home screen in Android to this page.

When this shortcut is clicked I would like to detect whether the network is available or not. Is that currently possible? Is there some JavaScript event I can catch when the shortcut is clicked?

(Reloading the page works OK, the network condition is discovered as I expect it too. However the page is not reloaded when the shortcut is clicked.)

How about the situation with other web browsers etc?